# Loop Not Completing In Bash

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu

I am making this Bash script (see below) that should check if a Node.JS file is running, if it's not - it will restart the file and continue with the loop. However when it attempts to run the file, it doesn't continue.

This will be running on Ubuntu, but I am checking it on Windows 10 at the moment. I know I could use Nodemon, but I would prefer to use this.

Without the the `node %NAME`, the loop runs fine - so I'm guessing it may be because once it attempts to start Node.JS it doesn't continue, or I am running node wrong with Bash, howvever I have looked on another question, and it seems I am doing it right.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="Run.js"
RUN=`pgrep -f $NAME`

while true
do
    if [ "$RUN" == "" ]; then
        echo "Script is not running"
        node $NAME
    else
        echo "Script is running"
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: The script blocks until `node` exits, at which point it continues at the point just after where `node` was started. The loop itself *never* exits. Perhaps you want to run `node` in the background, then use `break`?

Comment: [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) is an effective process manager, why not use that and save yourself the hassle?

Comment: @PBurke I could, but 1. This is something for me to get some experience with bash, so in any case where I need it, I can. 2. It's a project I working on. So probably will use it sometime, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**for the study case**
 to avoid node from blocking the script
all what you need to do is to add &

```
 node $NAME &
```

with that being said there is a better alternative to keep a
 script running I recommend you as
@P Burke mention to read about PM2 http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="Run.js"
RUN=`pgrep -f $NAME`

while true
do
    if [ "$RUN" == "" ]; then
        echo "Script is not running"
        node $NAME &
    else
        echo "Script is running"
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```